# looping through customViews in a viewgroup, as that custom view

Tags: android, kotlin

I have a grid full of a custom view I've created. I can easily loop through it using `for (item in grid) {}` and I can then set things such as onClick etc.
However, my custom View has it's own functions which I would like to access and kotlin has no way of knowing item is always going to be type CustomView (It definitely will be though) so I wanted to do something like:

```kotlin
for (item in grid as CustomView) {
    item.customFun()
}
```

I must be missing something here because it gets marked with this cast can never succeed, but I just need kotlin to know this will always be a CustomView

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here `for (item in grid as CustomView)`, you've used `grid as CustomView` that is trying to cast the `grid` as a `CustomView`, which is why the compiler is complaining `this cast can never succeed`.

You have to cast the item inside the body of the `for loop`

```
for (item in grid) {
    (item as CustomView).customFun()
}
```

`as` is an unsafe cast operator, which would throw `exception` when item won't be an instance of `CustomView`. There you can use `is` for type checking.

```
for (item in grid) {
    when(item) {
        is CustomView -> item.customFun()
    }
}
```

Comment: Holy crap I'm a twat. Thank you so much

Comment: Happens to everyone bro no big deal, You are welcome.